# merge two data frames by comparing two date columns with a condition and comparing two id columns of two different data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames df1 and df2

df1:

| l_id | c_id | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | c1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1b | c1 | 2021-02-20 |
| 1c | c2 | 2022-11-25 |
| 1d | c2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1d | c2 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1e | c3 | 2022-04-08 |
| 1f | c4 | 2022-06-12 |

and

df2:

| c_id | r_dt |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | 2023-01-01 |
| c1 | 2021-02-14 |
| c2 | 2022-11-25 |
| c2 | 2022-02-28 |
| c5 | 2022-11-12 |
| c4 | 2022-06-06 |

what I want to do is I want exact match of c_id of the two data frame and then and if 'dt' of df1 minas 'r_dt' falls between less than 7 days, then only two data frame merges. I want the joining in "inner" ways.

My expected result will exactly look like:
result_df:

| l_id | c_id | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | c1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1b | c1 | 2021-02-20 |
| 1c | c2 | 2022-11-25 |
| 1d | c2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1d | c2 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1f | c4 | 2022-06-12 |

I tried it like following:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("my_csv1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("my_csv2.csv")

#merging
merge_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',left_on=['c_id','dt'], right_on = ['c_id','r_dt'])
```

but this does not give me exact result. It just matches exact date, it does not compare whether day difference is less or equal 7 days or not.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

do it in two steps: merge on id first and then filter, like

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',left_on=['c_id'], right_on = ['c_id'])
merge_df = merge_df[(merge_df['dt'] - merge_df['r_dt']).dt.days.abs() < 7]
```

Comment: Hi, but the above answer is actually increasing the row count of my expected result. I dont want more rows than df1 have

Comment: That is how join work, if you have multiple matches you will increase the row count. If you don't want that, join against a unique index or specify duplicate handling accordingly